# Rust Analyzer type hint not working in VSCode

Tags: rust, rust-analyzer

I am new to Rust and experiencing some problem with the type hint in Rust Analyzer.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp9Tt.png)
Ideally, there should be a type hint for `is_morning` on line 9. But it doesn't work. All my settings are default. Please help me!

I tryied to add a line in the config file of VSCode like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqbwc.png)
But it says `"rust-analyzer.inlayHints.enable"` is a "Unknown Configuration Setting"

Comment: Iirc since native Inlay Hints have been implemented in VSCode a couple years ago, you have to enable them in editor settings, not in LSP client settings.

Comment: The editor's Inlay Hints is on, but it still doesn't give me a type hint when declaring a new variable.

Comment: You need to enable all the different kinds of inlay hints

Comment: You need to set `editor.inlayHints.enabled` to `"on"` I believe